# Chef: should I be checking "syntaxcache" files into version control?

Tags: ruby, git, version-control, chef-infra, gitignore

I'm learning Chef and am keeping my `chef-repo` in version control. When I use `knife cookbook upload` and then run `git status` I see a bunch of new files in `.chef/syntaxcache`. They look like this:

`.chef/syntaxcache/8ab66bdf1ceb07273f7b3d71f483fbd84be595e845e90ffcbeb0ba6d22f684b0`

Should I be adding these to version control or just put a pattern in `.gitignore` to leave them out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, most stuff under `.chef` are temp files. Specifically those are (I think) rendered versions of Erb templates so we can run a Ruby syntax checker on them. I'm kind of surprised we don't delete them afterwards though, that's probably a bug.

Comment: Should I open an issue?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt, but it would be a low-priority thang since it doesn't hurt much.

Comment: Doesn't .chef/knife.rb have useful information to track? Or can this be managed on a user-by-user basis?